# Spinner not displaying contents

Tags: android

so I have an app with 3 fragments. One of the fragments involves adding characters to a listview and then giving them weapons and abilities. Weapons and abilities are given to a characters via a custom dialog that appears when the Add button is clicked.
This dialog contains a spinner with a predetermined list of names of characters and then 3 edit-texts that require the user to enter the number of abilities that the characters is supposed to have.

My problem is that the spinner in this dialog is not displaying its contents.
Everytime I click on the dialog I get this :

*W/InputEventReceiver﹕ Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.*

Rewards.java

```
 public class Rewards extends Fragment {

    private Button button;
    Context mContext;
    int lesserCount;
    int greaterCount;
    int exaltedCount;
    Dialog addCharDialog;
    Dialog lesserDialog;
    Dialog greaterDialog;
    Dialog exaltedDialog;
    Spinner SpnLesser1;
    Spinner SpnLesser2;
    Spinner SpnLesser3;
    Spinner SpnGreater1;
    Spinner SpnGreater2;
    Spinner SpnExalted;
    Spinner SpnChar;

    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rewards, container, false);
        View addCharDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.character_add, container, false);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

            mContext = getActivity();
        // custom dialogs

        createAddDialog(addCharDialogView);
        createLesserDialog();
        createGreaterDialog();
        createExaltedDialog();   


        SpnLesser1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lesserspinner1);
        SpnLesser2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lesserspinner2);
        SpnLesser3 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lesserspinner3);
        SpnGreater1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.greaterspinner1);
        SpnGreater2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.greaterspinner2);
        SpnExalted = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.exaltedspinner);


        return rootView;
    }

public View createAddDialog(View addCharDialogView) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity());


    addCharDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    addCharDialog.setContentView(R.layout.character_add);
    addCharDialog.setTitle("Add a character");

    SpnChar = (Spinner) addCharDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.array.item_array, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(addCharDialogView.getContext(),R.array.item_array, R.layout.spinner_layout);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    SpnChar.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    //spinner is populated but it's not displaying and won't do anything when clicked on

    SpnChar.setSelection(2);

    String Text = SpnChar.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Log.d("2", Text);


    Button dialogOkButton = (Button) addCharDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogOkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            lesserCount = R.id.lessertext;
            greaterCount = R.id.greatertext;
            exaltedCount = R.id.exaltedtext;

            Character c;

            if (lesserCount > 0) {
                lesserDialog.show();
            }

            if (greaterCount > 0) {
                greaterDialog.show();
            }
            if (exaltedCount > 0) {
                exaltedDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    Button dialogCancelButton = (Button) addCharDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogCancel);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addCharDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            addCharDialog.show();
        }
    });

return addCharDialogView;
}

    }
}
```

character_add.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/dialog_label"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
    <!--android:hint="Please select an option"-->
    <!--/>-->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogOK"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogCancel"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialogOK"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialogOK" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/lessertext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText8"
    android:text="0" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/greatertext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText9"
    android:text="0" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/exaltedtext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText10"
    android:text="0" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText8"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="L" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lessertext"
    android:text="G" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_spinner"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/greatertext"
    android:text="E" />
```

Comment: did you try adding adding an onItemSelectedListener for your spinner?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of a game are you creating?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a spinner that can display the input the user types in? If so, you could use an Arraylist and create a method that will destroy your spinner and recreate it every time the contents changes. You could set it up as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> thing = new ArrayList<String>();
ViewGroup layout = null;
layout = (ViewGroup) spinner.getParent();

    public void addSpinner(ArrayList thing){

        layout.removeView(spinner);
                    layout.addView(spinnersy2); 

        spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);     
        ArrayAdapter <String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, thing);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

Create a second method that will add the user input into the array.